# Service Worker to identify the WindowClient that posted a message

Tags: javascript, service-worker

In my service worker I would to identify the exact window instance that triggered an event. For example, the two events I am particularly interested in are **message** and **notificationclick**:

**For the message event**

Some page does:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('hello');
```

And the service worker would like to reply a message just to that page:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then(function(windowClients) {
         // who sent me the message?
         let windowClient = ...
         windowClient.postMessage('world');
    }
})
```

**For the notificationclick event**

Some page does:

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {
     reg.showNotification('My Notification',{body: 'hi'});
 });
```

And in my service worker I would like to bring that window to focus

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then(function(windowClients) {
            // which window has created the notification?
            let windowClient = ...
            windowClient.focus();
        }
    )
})
```

From what I can tell, the windowClient does not have much on its own: it has a url and a id. **I cannot rely on url** because multiple pages of the same url might be opened, but I only want react to the exact window instance that triggered the event.

Id seems more promising, however how do I read the windowClient id in my page so that I can include it in the message/on the event data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the window client is stored inside the message event. e.g.:

```
const windowClient = event.source.id;
```

I am not sure about the notificationclick event, sorry.

Comment: This was helpful, for some reason MDN is very cryptic about the client id.